# Facing error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function

Tags: intel, intel-oneapi, sycl, dpc++

I was  running this code using SYCL and this error was coming up regarding recursion "error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function" I am not sure what is causing this error.
I used ordered set in the SYCL kernel and I am facing this issue not with the unordered set. I have mentioned the part of code below:

```html
sycl::buffer b1(sets);     
    q.submit([&](sycl::handler& h) {
        sycl::accessor a1(b1,h);
        h.parallel_for(sycl::range<1>(sets.size()), [=](sycl::item<1> it) {
            foo(a1[it]);//1st error source
            for (int i : a1[it]){ 
                i;
            }
        });
```

Error:

```html
   
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/set:60:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1886:26: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
              __top->_M_right = _M_copy(_S_right(__x), __top, __node_gen);
                                ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1875:7: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
      typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KoV, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1896:21: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
                  __y->_M_right = _M_copy(_S_right(__x), __y, __node_gen);
                                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1875:7: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
      typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KoV, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1903:6: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
            _M_erase(__top);
            ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1911:5: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
    void
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1000:9: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
      { _M_erase(_M_begin()); }
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1911:5: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
    void
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1918:4: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
          _M_erase(_S_right(__x));
          ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1911:5: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
    void
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:906:24: error: SYCL kernel cannot call a recursive function
          _Link_type __root = _M_copy(__x._M_begin(), _M_end(), __gen);
                              ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1875:7: note: function implemented using recursion declared here
      typename _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KoV, _Compare, _Alloc>::_Link_type
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:366:12: error: SYCL kernel cannot call an undefined function without SYCL_EXTERNAL attribute
        _M_node = _Rb_tree_increment(_M_node);
                  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:247:3: note: '_Rb_tree_increment' declared here
  _Rb_tree_increment(const _Rb_tree_node_base* __x) throw ();
  ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:364:7: note: called by 'operator++'
      operator++() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      ^
7 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: test_set] Error 1
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't use recursion in a SYCL kernel. It sounds like foo is recursive or calling something that is recursive. You would need to post the foo code in order for us to figure out if that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SYCL does not currently support recursive functions inside "device" code, i.e. a SYCL kernel.
See [the SYCL 2020 spec](https://registry.khronos.org/SYCL/specs/sycl-2020/html/sycl-2020.html#sec:language.restrictions.kernels) for confirmation.

[This blog post](https://codeplay.com/portal/blogs/2020/06/19/ray-tracing-in-a-weekend-with-sycl-part-2-pixel-sampling-and-material-tracing.html) has a section that talks about how to adapt code to avoid recursion using an example that might help under "Diffuse shading in the reference implementation - Recursive approach"