# How to move an array of structures to the GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, opencl

Lets say I created the tree and initilized it.
Now, how am I going to move nodes vector to the GPU in openCL?

```
struct BVHNode {
    BoundingBox bbox;
    BoundingSphere bsphere;
    std::vector<int> obj_triangles; // Store triangle indices that is inside node's volume
    int parentIndex; // Index of the parent node (-1 for root)
    int level;
    std::vector<int> childrenIndices; // Indices of the child nodes
}

class BVHTree {
public:
    std::vector<BVHNode> nodes;
    int maxDepth;
    int nodeSize;
}

I tried to move like this

size_t dataSize = bvhTree.nodes.size() * sizeof(BVHNode);
cl::Buffer d_BVHtree_buf(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, dataSize, BVHTree.nodes.data());

but it didn't work.
```

Comment: You need to move the whole structure *recursively*. Not just `BVHTree`. Indeed, `BVHNode` contains `std::vector` which contains allocated data on the host memory while it needs to be allocated on the device memory. This is cumbersome to do with this data structure because it is *not GPU-friendly*. In fact, `std::vector` is not GPU-friendly in the first place.

Comment: Even if you would succeed to do that, the structure layout is really not good for GPUs. You should read more about "coalescence" and "SIMT" to understand why. That being said, this is dependent of the computation : if the tree is small with large `obj_triangles` and such an array is computed, then it might be fine, but I guess this is not the case. Structures of arrays are generally much better for GPUs (possibly arrays of structures of arrays if needed).

Comment: To copy a data structure like `BVHTree` you need to implement what is know as a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy). FWIW, this need is independent of the use of a GPU. However, from a performance perspective it is questionable whether a data structure like `BVHTree` should be used on the GPU in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

GPUs support neither function recursion nor classes, and memory bandwidth is very poor for AoS (no coalescence).

Flatten the tree data structure into a structure of arrays layout. You might need to limit tree depth and add padding nodes such that data indices are regularly spaced. Alternatively, you can use indirect addressing, meaning adding an additional an array that contains the memory locations for nodes; this saves memory capacity but will kill memory coalescence. You can do fixed-depth recursion as a loop or chain of function calls.

Comment: Re "GPUs support neither function recursion". Maybe OpenCL doesn't but GPUs certainly do. Sample CUDA program: `#include <stdio.h> 
__device__ int fact (int i) { return (i == 0) ? 1 : i * fact (i - 1); }
__global__ void kernel (int i) { printf ("factorial of %d = %d\n", i, fact (i)); }
int main (void) { kernel<<<1,1>>>(6); cudaDeviceSynchronize(); return 0; }
`

Comment: As for support for classes, this may again be a limitation of OpenCL, but CUDA supports classes because it is essentially a dialect of  C++, so this is not a fundamental limitation of GPUs.

Comment: AFAIK OpenCL is mainly based on C so classes are not available but SYCL (which is based on C++) should. Both OpenCL and SYCL are developed by Khronos. It looks like SYCL also does [not support recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729502/facing-error-sycl-kernel-cannot-call-a-recursive-function) yet. Btw classes are an abstraction in programming languages while GPUs are hardware. The two live in different worlds (though compilers make the link between the two).